XHTML Document contains SVG namespace. Generating XML Schema Errors
I have an XHTML document with two namespaces.  That's because this XHTML document contains SVG tags and if the SVG namespace isn't included in the XHTML document, the SVG won't display on the webpage.
I created an XML Schema to validate this XHTML document.  But when I ran an XQuery, I received several errors that focused on the namespaced SVG elements.
I researched this topic both on this website as well as the XML Schema book published by OReilly media.  I also read through the Beginning XML book published by Wrox.
So far the tags XS:Any as well as the XS:annotation and XS:documentation elements have been suggested to solve these problems.  But since I've never come across this problem before and I've never used these instructions, I didn't know what the best approach to these problems would be.  Here is my XHTML code:
<html xmlns="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">
<head>
     <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
     <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js">
     </script>
</head>
<body onload="Setup()">
     <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Setup2()"/>
     <svg:svg id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
     <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
     <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
     </svg:svg>
</body>

Here is my XML Schema:
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:target="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" targetNamespace="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<complexType name="HeadType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="head" type="target:TitleType"/>
        <element name="body" type="target:BodyType"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="TitleType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="title" type="string"/>
        <element name="link" type="target:LinkType"/>
        <element name="script" type="target:ScriptType"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="LinkType">
    <attribute name="rel" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="type" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="href" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="ScriptType">
    <attribute name="language" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="src" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="BodyType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="input" type="target:InputType"/>
        <element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="onload" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="SvgType">
        <sequence>
        <element name="path" type="PathType"/>
        <element name="path" type="Path2Type"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id" type="string"/>
        <attribute name="height" type="string"/>
        <attribute name="width" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="InputType">
    <attribute name="type" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="id" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="value" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="onclick" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="PathType">
    <attribute name="id" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Path2Type">
    <attribute name="id" type="string"/>
</complexType>
<element name="html" type="target:HeadType"/>

And here are the errors that were generated:
Errors generated by XQuery
What do you suggest?
Update:
I fixed the PathType and several errors disappeared.  I tried to fix the SVG element by adding a xmlns:svg.  Then I added the svg prefix to the svg element.  This generated a couple of new errors.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.  Here is my corrected XML Schema schema element:
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:target="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" targetNamespace="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

And here is my corrected SVG element:
<svg:element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>

And here are the new errors:
New Errors
Further Update
I tried to isolate the errors.  So I downgraded my XMl Schema.  Based on my research, I've discovered that I'm associating many of my HTML Tags to the wrong namespaces.  But my efforts to correct this situation have so far proven unsuccessful.
As you can see in this code, I've created a new namespace called body.  Then I associated the body namespace with a couple of tags in the body section of my HTML.  I also associated the link and script tags to the body HTML.
    <xs:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:body="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xs = "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">
    <xs:head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
         <body:link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
         <body:script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js">
         </body:script>
    </xs:head>
    <body:body onload="Setup()">
         <body:input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Setup2()"/>
         <svg:svg id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
         </svg:svg>
    </body:body>
</xs:html>

And here is my abbreviated Schema:
 <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:schema = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xs = "http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
xmlns:body="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:target="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
targetNamespace="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <complexType name="HeadType">
     <sequence>
        <body:element name="head" body:type="target:TitleType"/>
        <body:element name="body" body:type="target:BodyType"/>
     </sequence>
     </complexType>
     <xs:element name="html" type="target:HeadType"/>
</schema>

And here is the new errors I receive when I run my xquery:
Namespace Errors
Another Update.  I was able to figure out why the script tag had an error.  Apparently there were some spaces between the opening and closing script tags.  So I used the / and eliminated the closing script tag.
I overlooked the fact that xmlns:target was the declaration of a namespace.  So I added xmlns:svg so that when I listed the SvgType, I could direct it to the correct namespace.
I have one more error to fix and I think this schema will finally validate my HTML.  Here is the error:
HTML validation error
I don't know why it won't validate my HTML tag.  I hope someone here can help me correct this error.
Here is another update:
As I stated earlier in this question, I decided to break the Schema line by line in an attempt to trace down the error.  I'm beginning to think that the namespaces in the HTML have little to no connection to the namespaces in my Schema document.
My current HTML Code:
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xml:lang = "en" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">
    <head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
         <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="Setup()">
         <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Setup2()"/>
         <svg:svg id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
         </svg:svg>
    </body>
</html>

And my simplified Schema document:
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:target="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
           targetNamespace="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="html" type="target:HeadType"/>
</xs:schema>

As you can see, I tried placing the schema element inside the xs: namespace.  I also tried to eliminate the xs: notation.  I've even tried to place the schema element inside the TedTheSpeedlearner.com namespace.  Nothing works.  So I hope someone can assist me.
Further update:
I added the following tag to my HTML:
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

And I changed all the namespace declarations to my html and to my schema:
<xs:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xml:lang = "en" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">

<schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:web = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:target="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">

And yet eXist doesn't recognize the HTML tag.  I don't know what to do next.
Further update:
I had to change the declaration of the schema location to finally convince the schema that my HTML tag really exists.  Here is my current HTML:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">
    <head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
         <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="Setup()">
         <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Setup2()"/>
         <svg:svg id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
         </svg:svg>
    </body>
</xs:html>

And here is my current XML Schema:
    <xs:schema xmlns:web="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:target="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <xs:complexType name="HeadType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="head" type="target:TitleType"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="target:BodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TitleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="link" type="target:LinkType"/>
            <xs:element name="script" type="target:ScriptType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
     <xs:complexType name="LinkType">
        <xs:attribute name="rel" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ScriptType">
        <xs:attribute name="language" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input" type="target:InputType"/>
            <xs:element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="onload" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="InputType">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onclick" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SvgType">
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PathType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="html" type="target:HeadType"/>
</xs:schema>

Notice that I had to add the xs namespace to all of my string types before this code would work.  But I still have one more error to overcome.  This involves the second namespace in my HTML document.  I had to add the SVG namespace to my project because it wouldn't work otherwise.  But I can't get the xml schema to recognize the svg namespace.  I'm not sure what to do next.
I've thoroughly researched the topic of using the schema import command and I developed a second schema.  Here is my second schema:
    <schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:target="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="SvgType">
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PathType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</schema>

I tried to use the schema import thinking to myself that the second namespace was interfering with the primary namespace of the first schema.  Unfortunately I received the same result as I did in image number 5 SVG Namespace.  I finally dumped the TedTheSpeedlearner namespace since it seems to have caused me so much trouble.  I'm still trying to figure out this problem.  I hope somewhere I can find the answer that will fix my problem.
I finally figured out my problem.  When I used SVG in my HTML document, I was forced for some unknown reason to use two namespaces.  The first was the SVG namespace and the second was the HTML namespace.  That's because I stored the data from my SVG into an XML document.
Apparently XMLSchemas only recognize one namespace when they validate instance documents.  The normal solution to this problem is to import another XMLSchema.  But apparently no one knows how to properly write a textbook.  It took me a long time to finally discover the ref attribute of an XMLSchema.  Therefore, my attempts to import a second schema into my main schema failed.  I will have to contact W3 and educate them on the concept of Keep It Simple Stupid.  I was writing in the COBOL and GWBASIC computer languages before some of them were even born.  I lived next door to a farm when I was young and I learned how to make everything simple.  Simply put, XMLSchemas aren't simple and they need to be redesigned to be simple.  What happened to creating Javascript modules to separate large chunks of code into easier to decipher pieces?


I am rather surprised that you should be writing your own schema for XHTML and SVG rather than using published schemas for these namespaces. But then I see this isn't XHTML, it's some very similar vocabulary but using a namespace of your own invention.
The reason it thinks PathType is in the xs namespace is that you have written
<element name="path" type="PathType"/>

with no prefix on PathType, and the default namespace for your schema is the xs namespace. You need to write target:PathType as you have done with other component references.
You're then going to hit problems with
<element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>

because that's declaring an svg element in your personal namespace whereas it is actually in the W3C SVG namespace.
UPDATED
Looking at the new information supplied, this is a real mess, you seem to be trying to get it to work by trial and error without understanding what any of the constructs you are using actually mean. I'd suggest that you stop fiddling with your code and spend a few days reading about the concepts and fundamentals.
A few basics:

Namespace URIs are important, namespace prefixes aren't, except that they should be consistent
There are three relevant namespaces here: the XML schema namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, the XHTML namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, and the SVG namespace http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
You can use any prefixes you like for these namespaces, but it's best to use the conventional ones: xs, xhtml (or h), and svg respectively. If you do things like binding the XHTML namespace to the xs prefix (with xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" then you're going to get everyone including yourself thoroughly confused.
Schemas for the XHTML and SVG namespaces already exist, you don't need to write your own, and if you think you need to write your own then you're doing something badly wrong.
I have absolutely no idea what the purpose of the namespace http://www.TedTheSpeedlearner.com is.


I tried to change the namespaces, but that caused my webpage to crash.  I've tried so many solutions and it only seems to make my webpage work worse than it works right now.  I'm totally at my wits end.

Sorry to hear about your frustration, but the only way to get help with a problem is to describe precisely what you did and precisely how it failed, rather than describing your emotional response to the failure.

I added information to my question to show you everything I've done so far to fix the HTML error.  But so far nothing has been successful.  I could use some good ideas right now.

Read on what?  I've read several webpages and the books Beginning XML, Professional XML, both published by Wrox, and even XML Schema published by OReilly.  And I'm no closer to finding the answer to this problem then when I started.  And only some of the things suggested here have been helpful.  How many books must I purchase and how many websites must I read to finally figure out what I'm doing wrong?

After much trial and error as well as much research into websites and books, I finally found the solution.  I had to create a second XML Schema.  Then I had to add an import statement to my first schema.  And then I had to add a ref to my xs:element statement.  Here is my first schema:
    <xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:target="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 schemaLocation="SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_SVG_Schema.xsd"/>
     <xs:complexType name="HeadType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="head" type="target:TitleType"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="target:BodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TitleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="link" type="target:LinkType"/>
            <xs:element name="script" type="target:ScriptType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
     <xs:complexType name="LinkType">
        <xs:attribute name="rel" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ScriptType">
        <xs:attribute name="language" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input" type="target:InputType"/>
            <xs:element ref = "svg:svg"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="onload" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="InputType">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="onclick" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="html" type="target:HeadType"/>
</xs:schema>

And here is my second XML Schema:
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:target="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="svg" type="target:SvgType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="SvgType">
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            <xs:element name="path" type="target:PathType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PathType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

My HTML page looks like this now:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml SVG_Bezier_Curve_Webpage_XML_Schema.xsd">
    <head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
         <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="Setup()">
         <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Setup2()"/>
         <svg:svg id="My_SVG" height="500" width="500">
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <svg:path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
         </svg:svg>
    </body>
</html>

I hope this answer helps people validate a HTML webpage with nested SVG elements. I plan to learn the language of JSON and I hope I will be able to access JSON using Javascript.  If this is possible, I may not have to utilize any database to extract any data from a JSON file.  And this would simplify all of my future project.
